# Highcharts: how to show more info in tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highchart. I have struggled in displaying more info in tooltip for a column chart.

I have the following categories:

```
Apple, Orange, Pear
```

I have the following series:

```
[["40%", 2], ["40%", 2], ["60%", 3]]
```

I am trying to show tooltips as something similar to the following. This is jsfidle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/qyc4v7fr/5/

```
Apple
2 selections, 40%
```

How can I do this?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer myself. Use the following for tooltip, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/qyc4v7fr/6/

```
tooltip: {
       formatter: function () {
             return this.x + '<br/>' + this.y + ' selections, <b>' + this.key + '</b>';
       } 
 }
```

Hope this helps others.